# First activity won't run on AVD

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I created an application, my first, and am having problems running it on an AVD. Won't load the first activity, just says 'Unfortunately, FussyFestivalrV7 has stopped. This is the main starting activity:

```
package com.example.fussyfestivalr;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

     switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, News.class);
             startActivity(intent);
         }
     });

}
}
```

And my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@string/title"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/newsbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:text="@string/news" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/exit"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/title"
    android:text="@string/exit" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bands"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/exit"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
    android:text="@string/bands" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/fafq"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bands"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
    android:text="@string/fafq" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/profiles"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/fafq"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
    android:text="@string/festivals" />
```

Comment: Make sure that the MainActivity is in your AndroidManifest file and that it is the Launcher activity

Comment: I believe so? 
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="activity_news"></activity>
    </application>

Comment: Does it work when you comment-out all the button stuff? Did it run right after you created the app with the wizard?

Comment: Can you share your Log?

Comment: It did work initially when I created the activity yes. As for my log, 03-17 15:02:25.295: E/AndroidRuntime(1581): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 15:02:25.295: E/AndroidRuntime(1581): Process: com.example.fussyfestivalr, PID: 1581
03-17 15:02:25.295: E/AndroidRuntime(1581): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fussyfestivalr/com.example.fussyfestivalr.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout

Comment: Something is wrong with your activity_main layout. Add it to your post

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have `</RelativeLayout>`.
I hope to help.

Paul.